# Get device information (such as product, model) from adb command

Tags: android, adb

One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
adb devices -l
```

example output:

```
123abc12               device product:<id> model:<id> device:<id>
456abc45               device product:<id> model:<id> device:<id>
```

But this list's out all devices connected, but I want to get the information for a specific device.
I want information only about "123abc12". The output should be:

```
123abc12               device product:<id> model:<id> device:<id>
```

The second device should not be shown.
I have the device name i.e 123abc12, and it can be used to get the required information, but I don't know how.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands)?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The correct way to do it would be:

```
adb -s 123abc12 shell getprop
```

Which will give you a list of all available properties and their values. Once you know which property you want, you can give the name as an argument to `getprop` to access its value directly, like this:

```
adb -s 123abc12 shell getprop ro.product.model
```

The details in `adb devices -l` consist of the following three properties: `ro.product.name`, `ro.product.model` and `ro.product.device`.

Note that ADB shell ends lines with `\r\n`, which depending on your platform might or might not make it more difficult to access the exact value (e.g. instead of `Nexus 7` you might get `Nexus 7\r`).

Comment: Nice. I just used this to pick out the correct APK for push to the device for my acceptance tests, which now run on my device or the emulator equally well.

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you try to grep the return of your command ?
Something like :

```
adb devices -l | grep 123abc12
```

It should return only the line you want to.

Comment: It seems to work, but I was wondering if adb has any such command.

Comment: According to the `adb --help` command there is no way to do this.

Comment: Seems so! Yours seems to be the best way. So I am accepting it :)
Thanks!