# Android UIAutomator how to check if phone or tablet

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

Is there a way to check if my app is running on a tablet or phone with uiautomator?  My tablet layout is much much different, the test code would be easier to follow if I could do a quick check to see which type of device I am running on.

Answer (score 0):

`getDisplayHeight()` gives you display size in dp

Source: [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#getDisplaySizeDp%28%29)

I guess you can use this to distinguish between your phone and tablet

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with specific list of devices then I would recommend getting device id or model number and build your logic on that. this will only work if you know what devices you are going to test on.

this should help in getting all related information from device.
[Get device information (such as product, model) from adb command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092118/get-device-information-such-as-product-model-from-adb-command)

If you don't know what device your test code might be running on in future then you will have to guess based on screen size like Anvesh mentioned. you can get other screen related details too to make more educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try -

```
getUiDevice().getProductName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `adb shell getprop` from the command line gives you a variety of device info and since uiautomator already runs in the device you could just use the processbuilder or `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` method to invoke the "getprop" command from your class and make use of the gsm.* properties to determine if the device is a phone or a tablet.