# Seeing the details of a device from the command line

Tags: android, command, avd-manager

I know that from Android Studio you can see the details of a certain device or AVD (eg. size screen, has camera or not,...) but I am unable to find the way to do it using command line.

With the command

```
avdmanager -v list device
```

I get

```
Parsing .....
id: 0 or "tv_1080p"
    Name: Android TV (1080p)
    OEM : Google
    Tag : android-tv
---------
id: 1 or "tv_720p"
    Name: Android TV (720p)
    OEM : Google
    Tag : android-tv
...
```

and I would like to see the details (hardware profile,...) for eg. "tv_720p"

Thanks!

PS: sorry if I mix some concepts, I have still some "dark spots" in this Android's world :-)

Comment: look also at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092118/get-device-information-such-as-product-model-from-adb-command#22882595

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/22882595/5186406
I Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but this is for running devices; I would like to know the properties forehand, before I create an AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I guess It's not possible to obtain every AVD (Hardware Profile Specification) with avdmanager.

Because with AVD manager you can create an AVD from already known hardware specification profile, the ones you see from

```
avdmanager list device
```

you already know every hardware specification.

What I suggest you is to create your own device hw spec for your specific scenarios so that you can use with avdmanager and your creation script.

```
s$ ./avdmanager list device | grep -A10 "My"
id: 6 or "My Device with 720dp Y"
    Name: My Device with 720dp Y
    OEM : User
---------
id: 7 or "Nexus 10"
    Name: Nexus 10
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 8 or "Nexus 4"
    Name: Nexus 4
    OEM : Google
```

Comment: Thanks but this is for running devices; I would like to know the properties forehand, before I create an AVD. I know this is possible with studio so probably it must exist a way in command line, or maybe the info is in a file ....

Comment: Okay so the question is not properly asked I guess. Why would you know the characteristics of a think that id doesn't still exists? Maybe you wanna prepare a file with some specs in order to build then an AVD with those characteristics?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have a misunderstanding with the concepts :-( : 
- When I execute "avdmanager -v list device", do I get a list of "device definitions" (eg. tv_1080p)? 
- Do those "device definitions" have a specific value for any of the properties (eg. for the device "tv_1080p" the screen resolution is X and for the device "tv_720p" the screen resolution is Y)?

If that's the case, I would like to know those "specific values" before I create an AVD based on a device. Or I am completely wrong and those devices do not have any value defined?

Comment: It's weird... I have found in the file [ANDROID_SDK]/tools/lib/devices.xml SOME devices definitions (Nexus One, Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7, Nexus 4 and Nexus 10) but NOT ALL (eg. "Android TV (1080p) (1080p)"). In fact I have found for the string "Android TV" for the entire HD without success :-(